# How to take data from textboxes in Django without using the automated model forms?

Tags: python, database, django, forms, model

I have a very simple thing I want to do, but for some reason I haven't found the solution yet. 
I have a form in HTML

```
<form id="user_form" method="POST" action="/ProjectName/home/">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="registerLabel">
        Full name:
    </div>
    <div class="registerTextLabel">
        <input type="text" id="registerFullName" class="registerTextDetails">
    </div>
    <div class="registerLabel">
        Username:
    </div>
    <div class="registerTextLabel">
        <input type="text" id="registerUsername" class="registerTextDetails">
    </div>

    <div id="registerButtonDiv">
        <button class="registerButtons" id="cancelRegisterButton">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="registerButtons" id="submitRegistration">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The thing I want is after filling this form and submitting it to take all the textbox values and put the in my database.

The db model is implemented like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

Here is the code of the view:

```
def register(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registed = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = User(data = request.POST)
        username = request.POST.get('registerUsername')
        password = request.POST.get('registerPass')
        user = form.save()
        username = User.username
        password = User.password
        u = User(username,password,...)
        u.save()
        registered = True
        else:
            form = User()

        return render_to_response('ProjectName/home.html', {'user_form':User}, context)
```

I do not want to use the automated way of Django where it generates forms from models.

Comment: where is your password input in the form?

Comment: Sry I put full name and username inputs instead of username and password. Now it's ok

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define name in the form. It is important for getting the POST data.

```
<form .........>
   {{error}}<br/><br/>
<div class="registerLabel">Username:</div>
<div class="registerTextLabel">
    <input type="text" id="registerUsername" name="registerUsername" class="registerTextDetails">
</div>

<div class="registerLabel" id="registerLabelPass">Password:</div>
<div class="registerTextLabel">
    <input type="password" id="registerPass" name="registerPass" class="registerTextDetails">
</div>
</form>

def register(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('registerUsername')
        password = request.POST.get('registerPass')

        if username and password:
            username_exist = User.objects.filter(username=username)
            if username_exist:
                error = username is already taken, try another
            else:
                User.objects.create(username=username, password=password)
                registered = True
        else:
            error = all fields are required

    return render_to_response('ProjectName/home.html', {'error':error}, context)
```

Comment: So the POST method takes the values of the textbox based on the name of the textbox right? I thought i was from the ID. request.POST.get('textboxName') is the correct way to take this value? Although it seems correct, it still does not work :/

Comment: It does not show an error. It goes to the home.html page but the data were not stored in the db :/

Comment: is this the correct path of your register: <form id="user_form" method="POST" action="/ProjectName/home/">?

Comment: I update the return render, it must be after the if statement sorry. After that tell me what is the error and don't forget to print the error in the template

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this 
username = User.username
password = User.password

be

User.username = username 
 User.password = password

Answer (score 0):

This is my html file:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <h6 class="dress"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a> <i> </i> Register </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <h2>PRODUCTS</h2>
    </div>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="register">
        <h3>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h3>
              <form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="mation">
                    <div>
                        <span>User Name</span>
                        <input id="id_username" maxlength="150" name="username" type="text" required />
                        <span class="helptext">Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</span></p>
                    </div>
                     <div>
                         <span>Email Address</span>
                         <input id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="text" />
                         </div>
                         <div>
                            <span>Password</span>
                                <input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password" required />
                    </div>
                             <div>
                            <span>Confirm Password</span>
                                <input id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password" required />
                    </div>
                     </div>
                     <input type="submit" value="Register">
                </form>


           </div>
            </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Now You can see my RegisterFrom:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Confirm Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        try:
            if ((password1 and password2) and (password1 != password2)):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Password Do not Match")
        except:
            pass
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Like this I am using custom textboxes in Django